# Sublime Text 2 - Auto Refreshing

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using the Sublime Text 2. My problem is that when I create a new file or folder, while using submline. It does not refresh and update immediately.

I have to quit out of sublime and restart it, I use the terminal to open folders. Once I reopen it then, I see the new file or folder I created.

I have looked for solutions, but I could not find one with an answer.

Thanks

Comment: I have noticed something like that, but it doesn't happen all the time.  A quick fix is to use: *Project -> Refresh Folders*.

Comment: That seemed to work as a quick fix. However, I would have to continue project -> Refresh as I create more files and folders.

Comment: There must be something else going on with your system.  I would start from stratch and see if the problem happens with the default settings and no packages.  Move/rename your [sublime-text-2 folder](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory), then reopen Sublime.

Comment: @jmoon90 are the folders on a remote host? I get this issue with our dev site files which are on a remote host. I only have this issue with this remote host, local hosted files refresh instantly.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of auto refresh we can do this

- Open Sublime Text.
- Select Preferences from the top menu and click Key
  Bindings – User.
- Add the following entry between the brackets.

  { `"keys": ["f5"], "command": "refresh_folder_list" }`

You should be able to refresh the folders with F5.

Comment: Good interim fix for me.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I try hitting F5 all the time anyway. Just never thought of adding it as a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

For auto refresh you should install Autorefresh

1. press crtl+shift+p
2. package control : install package

   wait for few seconds.
3. type autorefresh and press enter

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Auto%20Refresh